# cakephp Additional method in Model causes 500 Error

Tags: model, cakephp-1.2

Hey,
I am trying to optimise a couple of cakephp controllers with some additional methods in the model but am getting a 500 Internal Server error returned. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Model:

```
function getID($id) {
 $tmp = $this->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('Model.id'=>$id)));
 return $tmp;
}
```

Controller:

```
function getTotalQuestions(){
 $tmp=$this->Model->getID(7);
 debug($tmp);
}
```

Occasionally I don't get a 500 error, but an error message telling me no variable has been passed to getID.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Taff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how you are wording your functions (most likely). You need to change the format of the function names:

```
function get_id($id = null) {
   // code here
}

function get_total_questions() {
   $tmp = $this->Model->get_id(7);
  // ...
}
```

Take a look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/908/Requirements#!/view/904/Controller-Conventions for more details. But it states:

> the convention is that your urls are
>   lowercase and underscored, therefore
>   /red_apples/go_pick is the correct
>   form to access the
>   RedApplesController::go_pick action.

Comment: Thanks...and sorry for the late reply. I got side tracked :-)